# Unchecked or unsafe operations when obtaining instance of java.lang.Class

Tags: java, reflection

When I use this code

```
Class clm = itt.apa.labs.Message.class;

if (!(clm.isAssignableFrom(cl))) {
  System.out.println("Class not implements Message!");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

I have de this result saying:

```
[javac] Note: /.../Step5.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

But when I do this:

```
if (!(itt.apa.labs.Message.class.isAssignableFrom(cl))) {
  System.out.println("Class not implements Message!");
  System.exit(1);
}
```

I don't have any note.

I already read some things about the generics but I didn't understand why this is happening in this case.

Any help? Can anyone explain me why?

Comment: ask compiler for answer using `javac -Xlint:unchecked filename.java`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class clm
```

should be

```
Class<itt.apa.labs.Message> clm
```

Class is a generic type, and you're using it as a raw type.

Comment: Ok! Thanks a lot JB Nizet. Now I understand, makes sense.